# SQL - Compare one column to some column to find match value

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

I have some dataset and I will compare it with self join

The thing is, I want to compare Column A with Column B, C, and D.
If column A has no match with all of the three column, then I will insert it to table.

Otherwise, if column A has matching value with at least one of column B, C, or D then I will not insert the value.

Here is my example data

```
ID     ColA     ColB     ColC     ColD
1      ORANGE   RED      BLUE     GREEN
2      RED      YELLOW   RED      PURPLE
```

Here is my expected result. Since `ID 1` has not match value, then it will be inserted, and `ID 2` will not be inserted

```
ID     ColA     ColB     ColC     ColD
1      ORANGE   RED      BLUE     GREEN
```

I tried `LEFT JOIN` but ID 2 still in the result

```
select a.*
from TableA a
left join TableA b
on a.ID = b.ID
where 1=1
and (a.ColA <> b.ColB
  OR a.ColA <> b.ColC
  OR a.ColA <> b.ColD)
```

Is there something I miss?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks @Dale K for helping me, right now I add some dataset regarding our comments.

If there are `NULL` values on ColB, ColC or ColD
How do I get the expected results with data below

```
ID     ColA     ColB     ColC     ColD
3      YELLOW   NULL     YELLOW   RED   
4      RED      NULL     NULL     RED
5      GREEN    NULL     BLUE     RED
```

Since only ID 5 has no match value with ColA, here is the expected result

```
ID     ColA     ColB     ColC     ColD
5      GREEN    NULL     BLUE     RED
```

Thanks

Comment: `ColA not in (ColB, ColC, ColD)` as long as no nulls.

Comment: LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. After a LEFT JOIN a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a join, and you want `AND` not `OR` i.e. you want all the conditions to be true, not just one of them.

And assuming ColA can never be null or blank gives

```
select a.*
from TableA
where ColA <> coalesce(ColB,'') and ColA <> coalesce(ColC,'') and ColA <> coalesce(ColD,'');
```

This will however match if ColB & ColC & ColD are all null.

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ColA EXCEPT SELECT ColB INTERSECT SELECT ColC INTERSECT SELECT ColD)` does the trick also, and deals with nulls correctly, notice that your version will return true if `ColA` is `''` and `ColB` is `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
    select *
    from TableA 
    where  (ColA <> ColB
    AND ColA <> ColC
    AND ColA <> ColD)
```

Comment: its kinda important to point out the change from or to and... since that is in fact what OP got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with nulls correctly (null equals null but not blank `''`) then you need the following

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT a.ColA
  INTERSECT (
    SELECT a.ColB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.ColC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.ColD
  )
);
```